# how to copy files from /mnt/sdcard to application directory using process builder

Tags: android, adb, processbuilder

I want to copy files from **/mnt/sdcard** to application directory using process builder

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "su", "cat   /mnt/sdcard/debug_settings.txt > /data/data/com.sample.project/filetest.txt" });

Process process;
    try {
        process = builder.start();
         /*InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(line);
            }*/
         int suProcessRetval = process.waitFor();
            Log.d("Sahil", "suProcessRetval ="+suProcessRetval);
            System.out.println("Program terminated!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
         Log.e("Sahil", "Could not run process", e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       }

 }
```

Not sure how can i proceed further.

if i run

```
"cat/mnt/sdcard/debug_settings.txt > /data/data/com.sample.project/filetest.txt"
```

from shell, it had copied the contents.

Comment: So, what error or message do you have in log?

Comment: No Error, it just simply not copied. Do you know any other method to do above ?

Comment: Other method to copy? yeh, FileInputStream + FileOutputStream

Comment: No i want to copy/move files using adb command only(programtically) tried below way also:
 String[] comando = {"sysrw","mv /mnt/sdcard/debug_settings.txt /data/data/com.sample.project/filetest.txt","sysro"};
 Process suProcess;
try {suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(suProcess.getInputStream());
for (String tmpCmd : comando) {
 os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");}      //res.add(osRes.readLine());os.writeBytes("exit\n");os.flush();int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();